# Make dropdown menu like Facebook share dialog on iphone

Tags: ios

Anyone know of a good framework for creating a dropdown menu like the one found on the Facebook share dialog?

[image: facebook share dialog dropdown menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIActionSheet` to achieve the same

http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I found a great framework for it:

https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController